# How to integrate a 3rd party script into my html code and pass values to the script?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to integrate a 3rd party (payment gateway button) code into my html code. In the following code, div tag is my html code and script tag is the said code to be integrated. If I hardcode the script tag as below it works fine. Now I want to have 'data-amount' variable and set its value. What are my options?

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Cart Subtotal:</td>
        <td class="text-medium" id="SubTotal">$0</td>
    </tr>           
</table>
<div>   
 <script                             
  src="https://secure.payments.com/scripts/eCrypt.min.js"
  class="paynow-button"
  data-publicapikey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  data-amount="1234;" data-currency="USD">
 </script>
</div>
```

Note: I have the value for 'data-amount' in a js file which is included into html file. For other html fields I set the 'data-amount' dynamically in a js file as follows:

```
var subTotalVal = get Value From cockie;
document.getElementById("SubTotal").innerHTML = "$" + subTotalVal;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can access it through `dataset`

```
const script = document.querySelector('SCRIPT TAG ID OR CLASS OR WHATEVER SELECTOR');
script.dataset.amount = '1234'
```

or you can get data by `const amount = script.dataset.amount`(can be both getter and setter)

Comment: sorry, I am not good at html / javascript. can you please elaborate?

Comment: @amit Well, I cannot understand your Note. Where is #SubTotal and what is a subTotalVal variable?

Comment: I have added more details to the question, hope its clear now